# How to raise an event from a stub returned from a stubbed factory?

Tags: c#, .net, events, nunit, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to unit test a class that does multithreaded processing of video files. The class under test is ParallelTranscoder.

ParallelTranscoder depends on a factory to create a new transcoder for each item in it's queue. So I'm creating a stub IAsyncTranscoder, and a stub IAsyncTranscoderFactory. Then I feed the transcoderStub to the factory so that it's handed out when transcoderFactoryStub.Create() is called.

The IAsyncTranscoder needs to raise an event when it has finished processing, so the stub is set up to raise it's FinishedEvent as soon as it's TranscodeAsync() is called.

All of this is working in the first test method where I only enqueue one item.
In the second test method though, it fails with this message:

> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred.
>     ----> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred.
>     ----> System.InvalidOperationException : This action is invalid when the mock object is in replay state.

The line that throws the exception seems to be the `transcoderStub.Raise(t => t.FinishedEvent += null,...` inside the CreateTranscoderStub() method.

Is this because Rhino Mocks maybe isn't thread safe or am I just doing it wrong? (I'm new to Rhino Mocks)

Regardless of the cause, is there a way to do this?

```cs
[TestFixture]
class ParallelTranscoderTests {

    [Test]
    public void Transcode_FinishWithoutError_RaisesFinishedEvent() {

        var transcoderStub = CreateTranscoderStub();

        var transcoderFactoryStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IAsyncTranscoderFactory>();
        transcoderFactoryStub.Stub(stub => stub.Create()).Return(transcoderStub);

        bool transcodingFinishedEventWasRaised = false;

        var transcoderUnderTest = new ParallelTranscoder(concurrencyLevel: -1, transcoderFactory: transcoderFactoryStub);

        // Subscribe to the event and set a flag if it's called
        transcoderUnderTest.FinishedEvent += (sender, args) => { transcodingFinishedEventWasRaised = true; };

        transcoderUnderTest.EnqueueTranscodeItem(new TranscodeItem());
        transcoderUnderTest.Transcode();

        Assert.That(transcoderUnderTest.TranscodingFinished, Is.True);
        Assert.That(transcodingFinishedEventWasRaised, Is.True);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Transcode_TwoItemsFinishWithoutError_RaisesItemFinishedEventTwiceAndFinishedEventOnce() {

        var transcoderStub1 = CreateTranscoderStub();
        var transcoderStub2 = CreateTranscoderStub();

        var transcoderFactoryStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IAsyncTranscoderFactory>();

        transcoderFactoryStub.Stub(stub => stub.Create()).Return(transcoderStub1).Repeat.Once();
        transcoderFactoryStub.Stub(stub => stub.Create()).Return(transcoderStub2).Repeat.Once();

        int timesTranscodingFinishedEventWasRaised = 0;
        int timesItemFinishedEventWasRaised = 0;

        var transcoderUnderTest = new ParallelTranscoder(
                                            concurrencyLevel: -1,
                                            transcoderFactory: transcoderFactoryStub
                                      );

        transcoderUnderTest.FinishedEvent += (sender, args) => {
            timesTranscodingFinishedEventWasRaised++;
        };
        transcoderUnderTest.ItemFinishedEvent += (sender, args) => {
            timesItemFinishedEventWasRaised++;
        };

        transcoderUnderTest.EnqueueTranscodeItem(new TranscodeItem(){InFile = "item1_in", OutFile = "item1_out"});
        transcoderUnderTest.EnqueueTranscodeItem(new TranscodeItem(){InFile = "item2_in", OutFile = "item2_out"});

        transcoderUnderTest.Transcode();

        Assert.That(transcoderUnderTest.TranscodingFinished, Is.True);
        Assert.That(timesTranscodingFinishedEventWasRaised, Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(timesItemFinishedEventWasRaised, Is.EqualTo(2));

    }

    private static IAsyncTranscoder CreateTranscoderStub() {
        var transcoderStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IAsyncTranscoder>();
        transcoderStub.Stub(stub => stub.TranscodingFinished).Return(true);
        transcoderStub.Stub(stub => stub.TranscodeAsync()).WhenCalled(delegate {
            transcoderStub.Raise(t => t.FinishedEvent += null,
                                 transcoderStub,
                                 new TranscoderFinishedEventArgs
                                     (true, DateTime.Now,
                                      DateTime.Now, 0));
        });
        return transcoderStub;
    }
}
```

Comment: After some more testing I realized that the test fails when I run only Transcode_TwoItemsFinishWithoutError_RaisesItemFinishedEventTwiceAndFinishedEventOnce(). However, when I run all the tests in the class it passes. (the class currently contains around 40 test methods).
This leads me to believe there is some kind of race condition.

Any thoughts on this?